# Creating DLL for C# using C and Fortran

Tags: c, dll, fortran

I have some legacy code written in C and Fortran. I've figured out some input and output parameters for the code. I'm trying to create a .DLL with C and Fortran, so I can conveniently use them in a form application. I'm using the following commands to do so:

First, create object files for Fortran and C files:

> gfortran -c *.f
>
> gcc -c *.c

Then, put them all together with the following command:

> gfortran -shared -mrtd -o theCode.dll *.o

I'm getting errors such as
"multiple definition of `func_`"
"undefined reference to `anotherfunc_`"

My questions are:
1) Is my method correct in creating the .dll file?
2) Why am I getting these errors?

I will provide more information upon request. Thank you!

Comment: Typically you'd just invoke ld for the final link stage. Also, those errors probably mean exactly what they say. You've defined a function twice, and another one not at all.

Comment: How this is related to C#?

Comment: I don't know, how `gfortran` handles function names, but `ifort` always appends an underscore. So if you want to call a function `func` in Fortran, this function has to be defined as `func_` in C. (This behaviour can be changed with various compiler flags.)